# How to determine if a system of equations has a solution using the rank of a matrix

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-rank

Consider this problem:

Given are the matrix $A$ and the vector $\mathbf{b}$ with $ \alpha $  and $\beta  \in \Bbb R $;

[image]

$$

State for which alpha and beta the linear system of equations $$ A \cdot x = \mathbf b $$ has none, one or infinite number of solutins.

Now what I tried to do is set up a system of equations. That looks like this

$$ \begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 2 | 5\\
1 & 3 & 4 | 6 \\
2 & 4 & a | b
\end{matrix} $$

Now the goal is to get $0 \ 0 \ a$ in the last line so what I did i took the $-2$ second line and added it to the 3rd. So we get

$$ \begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 2 | 5\\
1 & 3 & 4 | 6 \\
0 & 2 & -8+a |-12+ b
\end{matrix} $$

Than I had to get rid of the so I took $-2 \cdot 1 + 3$ and I got.

$$ \begin{matrix}
0 & 1 & 2 | 5\\
1 & 3 & 4 | 6 \\
0 & 0 & -4+a |-22+ b
\end{matrix} $$

Now I've look at the cases when when the system has no solutions. That is when $\operatorname{rank} (A) < \operatorname{rank}(A|b)$. Now I'm not sure how I can  confirm the rank of a matrix, I would assume the rank is 3 because we have 3 lines. So if the rank of $A$ is 3 than the rank of $(A|b)$ has to be 2 or lower. Now if I want to get a rank 2, $(A|b)$ do I have to set  $\alpha=0$?

Because than we would have all $0$ in the last line thus the rank would be $2$. Some insight would be great. Thank you!

PS: If the solution to my system is false, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\alpha=4$. Then you have the matrix$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}0&1&2&5\\1&3&4&6\\0&0&0&b-22\end{array}\right].\tag1$$The matrix to the left of the vertical bar has rank $2$ (the rank is the number of linearly independent lines, whereas the rank of $(1)$ depends upon $b$: it is $3$ if $b\ne22$, but it is $2$ if $b=22$. So, if $b\ne22$, the system has no solutions, but it has solutions if $b=22$.

And if $\alpha\ne4$ *both* matrices have rank $3$, and therefor the system has solutions.

Comment: Okay excellent answer,now I know what was meant by Rank(A) and Rank(A|b) Although I have question.Now we know when the system has a solution and when it doesnt have a solutions,but when does the system have ONLY one solution.We would need the ranks to be equal  2 = 2 for example and be equal to n. Now I dont know if this is possible but I am not getting there,although the question explicilty states it is possible. Any thought?

Comment: The system has one and only one solution when and only when both ranks are equal to $3$.

Comment: Okay so when alpha is not equal to 4 and when betha is any real number; So like this? $$ \alpha != 4 & \beta € R $$

Comment: Yes: in that case, and only in that case, the system has one and only one solution.

Comment: If you want to write $\alpha\ne4\wedge\beta\in\mathbb R$, then type `$\alpha\ne4\wedge\beta\in\mathbb R$`.

Comment: Okay thans for the heads up,also thank you for your answer!